# How can I change the bottom text in grub2?

Tags: grub2

How can I change the bottom text (the text under the box that has something like 'press e to edit commands, press c for a command line, the selected os will boot in --'?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the native English version of Ubuntu, you will need to change the source and recompile.

If you use a translated version, or an English dialect (like Canadian, Australian, etc.) you can do the following:

1. Install [poedit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/poedit).
2. Go to [this page](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/tree/po?h=ubuntu/cosmic) and download the file ending in `.po` that corresponds to your *locale* (if necessary, use the `locale` command to find out which language you are using).
3. Open the file with `poedit`. Find the line that translates "press `e` to edit..." to your own language, and change the translation to whatever you want.
4. Compile to a `.mo` file. Store this file in `/boot/grub/locale`, overwriting the current `.mo` file. (Even better: make a backup first.)
5. Reboot. Grub will show your changed translation.

Disclaimer: I did not try this out, but I'm pretty sure it works this way, and if not, no harm is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own theme (without recompiling grub) that creates a graphical grub screen containing anything you like:

[image: grub boot.gif]

Reference: [Grub2 theme tutorial](http://wiki.rosalab.ru/en/index.php/Grub2_theme_tutorial)

---

## Bottom line setup

This is the text that creates the bottom line (below menu box):

```
+ hbox {
    top = 100%-50
    left = 9% # Was 20%

#    + label { text = "↑↓" font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "#87a556" }
    + label { text = ": Highlight       " font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "gainsboro" }
    + label { text = "ENTER" font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "#87a556" }
    + label { text = ": Boot       " font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "gainsboro" }
    + label { text = "e" font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "#87a556" }
    + label { text = ": Edit       " font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "gainsboro" }
    + label { text = "c" font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "#87a556" }
    + label { text = ": Command Line     " font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "gainsboro" }
    + label { text = "ESC" font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "#87a556" }
    + label { text = ": Return to Menu" font = "Ubuntu Regular 20" color = "gainsboro" }
}
```